# Evaluate $\int\limits ^{0}_{-\infty }\frac{\ln( t+1)}{t^{2} +1} dt$

Tags: definite-integrals

I have been trying to solve this integral for some time now

$\int\limits ^{0}_{-\infty }\frac{\ln( t+1)}{t^{2} +1} dt$.

and all the calculators I've used say it's equal to $\frac\pi4\ln(2)-G+\frac{π^{2}i}{4}$ ($G$ is Catalan's Constant), but I find that it's equal to $\frac\pi4\ln(2)-G+\frac{3π^{2}i}{4}$.

I can't seem to find the error, if any, in what I've done
$\int\limits ^{0}_{-\infty }\frac{ln( t+1)}{t^{2} +1} dt=\int\limits ^{\infty }_{0}\frac{ln( -x+1)}{x^{2} +1} dx=\int\limits ^{\infty }_{0}\frac{ln( x-1)}{x^{2} +1} dt+\frac{π^{2} i}{2} =-G+\frac{π}{4} ln( 2) +\frac{3π^{2} i}{4}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The outcome depends on the definition of $\log(t+1)$ for $t+1<0$. What is yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in applying the identity
$$\ln{(-x)}=\ln{(x)}+i\pi\quad\forall x\in(0,\infty)$$
when $x\lt0$. You should get
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln{(-x+1)}}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln{(-x+1)}}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln{(-x+1)}}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln{(x-1)}-i\pi}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln{(x-1)}+i\pi}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln{(x-1)}}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x+\left[-i\pi\arctan{(x)}\right]_0^1+\left[i\pi\arctan{(x)}\right]_1^\infty\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln{(x-1)}}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}$$